# problem in clearing Laravel5.7 cache (memcached driver)

Tags: laravel, docker, memcached, laravel-5.7

I have upgraded my application laravel version to 5.7 . cache driver is memcached. also i'm using docker compose with separate container for memcached, application, and webserver.

When I try cleaning cache it returns **`Failed to clear cache. Make sure you have the appropriate permissions`**.

when I change the cache driver to file it works well. Also, when I'm not running it in docker space it works well!

The problem is probably about *flushing memcached*. because when i try to clear it manually in my application it returns error **19** which stands for `Memcached::RES_SOME_ERRORS`! and I dont know what this means exactly!

p.s. and yes, I've created the `data` folder in `storage/framework/cache` directory with appropriate permissions.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as I'm using docker i should define hosts as conatiner names.
so I defined `MEMCACHED_HOST=memcached` in `.env` file :-"
also i defined application dependency for memcached container.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are trying to set up a routine cronjob to clear the cache.

Try running the clear command while you're logged on in a wheel user account

> sudo php artisan cache:clear

If it works, you may need to set up that cacheclear on an account with an appropriate access level for memory management tasks.

Comment: thanks for your answer; but i tried running the command with sudo too. doesnt worked :(